# Routing With ID in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-router

I need help in my routing in Angular 4. I want to display the URL like this. Localhost:4200/user/1 if i clicked the view details of the first user. I'm a bit confused on how to to this. I've tried my best in my code below but it still doesn't work.

> app-routing.module.ts

```js
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
        { path: 'user', component: UserComponent, children: [
            
            { path: 'create-new-user', component: CreateNewUserComponent },
            { path: 'user-list', component: UserListComponent },
            { path: 'user-detail/:id', component: UserDetailComponent },

    ]},
    ];
    
    
    @NgModule({
        imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
        exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {
    
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: I mean i can't go this this url  Localhost:4200/user/1. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 25):

I had this very problem a while ago. The problem here is the routes configurations you have. You cannot go to /user/1 because you defined the 'user-details' route as a child of the 'user' route. You either have to navigate to '/user/user-detail/1' or simply define a new child route with path ':id' pointing to your details component and you'll be able now to navigate to '/user/1'.

To sum up:
With the routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    ...
    { path: 'user', component: UserComponent, children: [

        ...
        { path: 'user-detail/:id', component: UserDetailComponent },

    ]},
];
```

you can navigate to '/user/user-details/1'.
With the routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    ...
    { path: 'user', component: UserComponent, children: [

        ...
        { path: ':id', component: UserDetailComponent },

    ]},
];
```

you can navigate to '/user/1'.
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 8):

In your routing file

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'user', component: UserComponent, children: [
    { path: 'create-new-user', component: CreateNewUserComponent }, 
    { path: 'user-list', component: UserListComponent },
    { path: ':id', component: UserDetailComponent }
  ]}
];
```

In your view method do like that

```
ViewuserDetail(user_id : any){
   let url: string = "/user/" + user_id
        this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
     }
```

In your template

```
<td><button class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="ViewuserDetail(user_object.id)">View</button></td>
```

Answer (score 7):

I think your `ViewDetail()` method needs an index parameter.
e.g.

```
public ViewDetail(index: number)
{
  this.index = index;
  ...
}
```

There's a great example [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5) for the routing itself.
They use the following route definition:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  ...
];
```

As for the typescript code.

```
gotoDetail(): void {
  this.router.navigate(['/detail', this.selectedHero.id]);
}
```

So, I think you're on the right track there.

I think it's just the index not being set.

Comment: @bvdb, how did you define the `router` in `gotoDetail()` method?

Comment: @Juniuz 
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; Then in your constructor define it like: constructor(public router: Router){}

Answer (score 3):

It should be something like this

```
  ViewDetail(index : any){
    this.router.navigate(['/user-detail', index]);
  }
```

If you want the url as listed `/user/1` then change the router configuration to match the name i:e instead of `user-detail` change to `user`

**UPDATE**

Ya there is change the template line to this

```
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="ViewDetail(i)">View</button></td> // it should be i instead of index
```

Comment: How about on other component and the user-list.html

Comment: in user list you have not defined a dynamic route see your router config `{ path: 'user-list', component: UserListComponent },` there is no `:id` here. from user list you will navigate to user detail there you will see a change in url

Comment: Still doesn't work. Maybe there's a problem in my ViewDetail button

Comment: @Joseph ya there is , i have updated the answer check it should be `i` instead of `index`

Comment: so, basically, you changed your answer and copied mine which was posted earlier. :) ... oh well, that's life I guess.

Comment: @bvdb i just looked at the OP question once again mine was path param and after he mailed i gave him a correct solution, he has child routes which he didnot mention in the question so it was not working. Also do look at the update the template is wrong it will be i instead of index ? so yours was not totally correct

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions, and exchanging email addresses is discouraged because it subverts the purpose of Q&A. If you are still having a problem, @Joseph, update the question with a [mcve].

Comment: LOL, sometimes looking through the comments can be a comic relief.