# Getting the text fields data from an array without API and showing that data based on the ID in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components one is having datatable another one having the data regarding that ID ..if once we click on the ID in that data table it will go to the other component  and it will show the entire details of that person in that input fields based on the ID we have to show the person's details ,here I am not getting how can I get the dummy data from an array and how can I keep that data into the text fields based on the ID

Comment: More details please, if possible can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: please provide some code, and what have you attempted so far to solve this problem?

Comment: please provide more code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is good answer - [Routing With ID in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45902521/routing-with-id-in-angular-4)

You can get this id throw ActivatedRoute, and find this item later.

Comment: Prefer flag as duplicate or mention exact answer instead of linking complete question